# Dynamically adding clips to container leads to random image slideshow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As I don't want to load all my 100 pictures to the movie clip container I decided to do this way:

1) Load the first 5 pictures and add them to movie clip container:

```
private function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
    {
        evt.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadingComplete);

        var bitmap:Bitmap=evt.target.loader.content as Bitmap;
        bitmap.smoothing=true;
        bitmap.width=stage.stageWidth;
        bitmap.height=stage.stageHeight;

        var clip_mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
        clip_mc.addChild(bitmap);
        clip_holderArray.push(clip_mc);

        container_mc.addChild(clip_mc);
```

2) At picture 4, transition from 4 to 5, I load other 5 and so on.

As loading is fast with just 5 pictures user doesn't notice loading...anyway something is not going right and I don't see pictures in the exact order I put them on the container..why?

Comment: The pictures are being placed in the container in whatever order they finish loading. This will be determined by each image's file size. If you want them to be placed in the container in a specified order, then one solution is to add the Loader itself to the container before loading the image.

Comment: Can I have an example, please? Even a tutorial link is fine

Comment: This actually similar to a question I answered a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780690/photo-load-order-mess-up-as3/14780982#14780982